# SOQL Lib how to test a sub query

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to test a sub query using [SOQL Lib](https://soql.beyondthecloud.dev/)

In the docs it says [will ignore all filters and relations](https://soql.beyondthecloud.dev/docs/basic-features#:%7E:text=will%20ignore%20all%20filters%20and%20relations) so how is this possible if I cannot create a relationship?

My example is to get all opportunities for an Account who's amount value is between 500 and 2,000

**Account Selector**

```
 public AccountSelector getOpportunitiesByAmount(Id account_id){
    with(SOQL.SubQuery.of('Opportunities')
        .with(Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.Amount)
        .whereAre(SOQL.FilterGroup
            .add(SOQL.Filter.with(Opportunity.Amount).greaterThan(500))
            .add(SOQL.Filter.with(Opportunity.Amount).lessThan(2000))
            .conditionLogic('1 AND 2')
        )
    )
    .whereAre(Filter.with(Account.Id).equal(account_id));

    return this;
}
```

**Controller**
The debug is to make sure that the expected result works which is does

```
    public static List<Account> getOpportunitiesInAccount(String account_id) {  
    // making sure it works      
    List<Account> accList = AccountSelector.query()
                            .getOpportunitiesByAmount(account_id)
                            .mockId('AccountController.getOpportunitiesInAccount')
                            .toList();
    Opportunity opps = accList[0].Opportunities;
    System.debug(opps.Amount);
     
    return AccountSelector.query()
                            .getOpportunitiesByAmount(account_id)
                            .toList();
}
```

**Test**

At the moment I am getting the error - System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

```
@IsTest
static void opportunityForAccountInRange(){ 

    List<Opportunity> opportunity_list = new List<Opportunity>{
        new Opportunity(AccountId = '0012o00003ORxRcAAL', Amount = 500),
        new Opportunity(AccountId = '0012o00003ORxRcAAL', Amount = 1500),
        new Opportunity(AccountId = '0012o00003ORxRcAAL', Amount = 2000)
    };
    SOQL.setMock('AccountController.getOpportunitiesInAccount', opportunity_list);


    Account account_for_test = new Account(Id = '0012o00003ORxRcAAL', Name = 'Test');
    SOQL.setMock('AccountController.getOpportunitiesInAccount', account_for_test);

    List<Account> result = AccountController.getOpportunitiesInAccount('0012o00003ORxRcAAL');

    // Opportunity opps = result[0].Opportunities;
    // System.debug(opps.Amount);
    
    Assert.areEqual(1, result.size());
    
}
```

I was hoping that if anyone has experience using SOQL Lib if they could help shed some light around testing sub queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test sub-queries you should use the deserialization mechanism with JSON data (to write on non-writable fields), [as described in the documentation](https://soql.beyondthecloud.dev/advanced-usage/mocking#sub-query):

> ### Sub-Query
>
> To mock a sub-query we need to use deserialization mechanism. There are two approaches, using JSON string or Serialization/Deserialization. Then after deserialization to desired SObjectType, pass the data to SOQL by calling `.setMock` method.
>
> #### Using JSON String
>
> By passing simple String, it is possible to write non-writable fields, like Name on Contact object.
>
> ```
> @IsTest
> static void getAccountsWithContacts() {
>    List<Account> mocks = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(
>        '[{ "Name": "Account Name", "Contacts": { "totalSize": 1, "done": true, "records": [{ "Name": "Contact Name", "Email": "contact.email@address.com" }] }  }],
>        List<Account>.class
>    );
>
>    List<Account> accounts;
>
>    Test.startTest();
>    SOQL.setMock('AccountsController.getAccountsWithContacts', mocks);
>    accounts = AccountsController.getAccountsWithContacts();
>    Test.stopTest();
>
>    Assert.isNotNull(accounts);
>    Assert.isNotNull(accounts[0].contacts);
>    Assert.areEqual(1, accounts[0].contacts.size());
> }
> ```

I suggest reading the documentation on this because it also explains how to use the `JSON.serialize` method to build the mocked data with lists and maps instead of a single string.